# Rellenar un input, con varios textos con Jquery y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Saludos, Estoy creando una ventana de ayuda similar inclusive a esta misma pagina, cuando uno escribe cierto carácter y se detecta, sale una ventana de ayuda y al dar click en ella se coloca dentro del input (En la sección de formular pregunta, en el input de etiquetas), Deseo hacer exactamente lo mismo. La forma en la que estoy haciendo es que el usuario al escribir cierto carácter me manda una petición a la base de datos y con ajax me sale una ventana con un pequeño boton, que al dar click lo que busco es que se coloque dentro del input, pero que permita colocar varios, no solo uno, hasta aquí quede ya que solo pude lograr que introduzca un solo input, si da click a otro se remplaza y lo que busco es que se vayan colocando acorde vaya dando click.

Este es el codigo HTML que se encarga de enviar las peticiones

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset-job_tags">
<label for="job_tags">Habilidades necesarias para este proyecto <small>(opcional)</small></label>

<div class="field ">

<input oninput="parameter();" type="text" class="input-text" name="job_tags" id="job_tags" placeholder="Ejemplo : php,marketing,traducción" value="" maxlength="60"  />

<small class="description"><strong>Indica las habilidades que debe poseer el freelancer para este proyecto</strong></small>

<script>
function parameter(){
// alert(jQuery("input[name=job_tags]").val());
jQuery.ajax({
url:"wp-admin/añadir-habilidades.php?ajax_method=accept",
method:"POST",
cache:false,
data:jQuery("#submit-job-form").serialize(),
success:function(data){
//   alert(data);
if(data!="" && (data!=null)){
jQuery("#modal").html(data);
}
jQuery("#modal").html(data);
},
error:function(data){
console.log(data);
}

});
}
</script>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Este es el codigo que el servidor le manda al cliente para que pueda rellenar el input con la petición ajax.

```html
public function filter($key){
try{
$stm = "SELECT * FROM habilidades WHERE habilidad LIKE ? LIMIT 1";
$FILTER = $this->BBDD->prepare($stm);
$FILTER->execute(array(htmlentities(addslashes("%$key%"))));
if($FILTER->rowCount()!=0){
foreach($FILTER->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $filters_category){
if(!empty($filters_category->habilidad) && ($filters_category->habilidad!="")){
echo "<div style='min-width:2em; display:block;' class='container'>
<div style='min-width:2em;' class=''>
<div style='min-width:2em;' class=''>
<div style='min-width:2em;' class=''>
<div style='min-width:2em;' class=''>
<button style='width:2em !important; height:0px;padding-bottom:30px;padding-top:10px;position:absolute; margin-top:-2.2em' type='button' id='modal_button' name='modal_button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>
<span id='val_span' style='margin-left:-2.8em; font-size: 10px;'>
$filters_category->habilidad
</span>

</button>

</div>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
echo "<script>
jQuery('#modal_button').click(
function(event){
jQuery('input[name=job_tags]').attr('placeholder','$filters_category->habilidad').attr('value','$filters_category->habilidad');
return false;
});
</script>";

}
}
}else{
return null;
exit;
}

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
die("Error en los filtros" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
}finally{
$this->BBDD = NULL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solamente guarda tu resultado anterior y le agregas el nuevo:

```js
function agregarhabilidad(attrib){
  var old=$('input[name=job_tags]').val();
  if (!old){
    old='';
  }else{
    old+=', '
  }
  $('input[name=job_tags]').val(old+attrib);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="job_tags">
<button onClick="agregarhabilidad('cazar')">cazar<button>
<button onClick="agregarhabilidad('volar')">volar<button>
<button onClick="agregarhabilidad('nadar')">nadar<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el Autocomplete de Jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```